# Vue loop through fetch api array objects and display in Spa with prev/next buttons and a default first view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch

I am building an app to display user data from api in Vue JS, and have got the top half of it done, but now moving on to trying to display the array objects with prev/next buttons, and a default view when the call is first made (taken from an entered search field)[image]

There are two get requests, one to the top level of api for general data (which is displayed as in pic above, and another to a specific section of it, the repos of a Github user. Ive layed out the boilerplate for this, and some of it is already in use, but wondering the best way to start this part. I want to load the last 50 repos of a user, and display a default one, say the most recent, with some attributes of it in template literals, and be able to prev/next button click to each one, which loads up in to a ul/h4, probably with v-for directive. The code Ive got laid out at present is as follows.

Input

```
<input
v-model="localValue"
@keypress="fetchData"
placeholder="Enter Github User Name">
```

Section being worked on (App.vue)

```
<section class="repodata text-center">
         <div class="controls">
          <btn class="btn-success btn-lg prev" @click="prev">Prev</btn>
         <!--<button class="btn-success btn-lg play" v-if="!isViewing" @click="play">View</button>-->
          <!--<button class="pause" v-else @click="pause">Pause</button>-->
         <button class="btn-success btn-lg next" @click="next">Next</button>
        </div>
           <b-card class="text-center">
           <b-card-title><h2 class="text-center section-title">Latest Repos</h2></b-card-title>
           <h4 v-for="repo in repos" v-bind:key="repo.title" class="repo-name">{{ repo.name }} - <span>{{ repo.description }}</span></h4>
           <ul class="list-group">
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Created: Created Repo Page</li>
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Updated: Updated Repo Page</li>
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Forks: Repo Forks Count</li>
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Watchers: Repo Watchers Count</li>
               <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Stars: Repo Stars Page</li>
            </ul>
           </b-card>
           <br />
            <ul class="list-group">
             <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">View Repo</a>
             <br />
             </ul>
        </section>
```

The export default methods so far.

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
   props: {
    value: String
  },
  data () {
     return {
     localValue: "",
     details: {},
     avatar_url: "",
     url_base: 'https://api.github.com/users/',
     //index: 0,
     isViewing: false,
     current: {},
     repos: []
    }
  },
  created () {
      this.localValue = this.value;
      this.$watch("localValue", value => {
      this.$emit("input", value);
      });
      //this.repos = this.repos[this.repo.title];
  },
  methods: {
        fetchData(e) {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
        fetch(`${this.url_base}${this.localValue}`)
          .then(res => {
            return res.json();
          }).then(this.setResults)
        }
        this.getRepos();
      },
       setResults(results) {
       this.details = results;
       document.querySelector(".profile-details").style.display = "block";
       document.querySelector(".repodata").style.display = "block";
       document.querySelector(".search-box").style.display = "none";
    },
       getRepos() {
         fetch(`${this.url_base}${this.localValue}` + '/repos')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            let repos = [];
            data.forEach(item => {
            repos = [...repos, ...Object.values(item)];
            });
            });
      },
  prev() {},
  view() {},
  next() {}
  }
}
```

The input is a watched localValue of value, the fetchData method gets the main data, sets the results as details in setResults and this is used for what is seen in the image above. Then it runs the getRepos method which gets the repos of the user (preferably just the last 50) which I want to put in the repos array to display as mentioned, with prev/next buttons. This is what I am trying to figure out the best way to do. I want to have a default latest repo loaded, with title/desc in the h4 (not working at the moment) and the other data in the list group items with a button to view/link to the repo. Any ideas on the best way to implement this?. The last 3 items in the data object are not in use yet, nor are the next,prev and view functions . The display section looks like the pic above, a ul list group, with a button at bottom to view the current repo and prev/next buttons at the top. Everything is in the one App.vue file, there are no  components.

UPDATE, its now currently like below, and just looking for best way to display first repo by default, then prev/next through the rest with the title/desc and some bits in the ul group.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Mind boiling this question down to something clear and specific? This question appears to be too long, detailed and unfocused. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes sure, just the best way to get the  getRepos() repos array item data in to the ul group, and prev/next through them. Thanks

Comment: Would this not be sufficient in the `getRepos` response: `.then(data => { this.repos = data })` If not, why not? Right now, without `this`, it only sets them to a variable in the method scope (overwriting itself as well) but does nothing with them.

Comment: OK Ive done that bit wrong, ill change that, but also looking for best way to display with a current, next, prev ? Thanks

Comment: Its working now, it is displaying the repos in the v-for with titles/description using "id" as key, so now want to set just the most recent  one at the start as default with the other bits in the ul group,, then prev/next through them all to show up one by one when clicked. Any tips? Code is at git@github.com:xhostcom/vue-github-finder-pwa.git Thanks

Comment: Also, if you put any tips in actual answer box I can check this as accepted answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by Dan , who pointed out I was overwriting the var and doing nothing, so having corrected that it works fine. Now just looking for way to set a default view with the latest repo and prev/next through the rest. Thanks